# Resign and become first responder in ios 8.3

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios8.3

I just "upgraded" to 8.3 and the logic that let me go from one UITextfield does not work any longer. Now with the following code when the user finishes with the text and automatically goes to the next field it clears the previous field. This works perfectly in earlier ios version. Any suggestions?  Thanks.  This is maddening.

```
} else if (alertView.tag == 1) {
        NSLog(@"it's tag ONE");
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            NSLog(@"YES");
            [defaults setObject:self.dobTextField.text forKey:@"DateOfBirth"];
            [defaults setObject:self.ageLabel.text forKey:@"Age"];
            NSLog(@"set dob: %@", self.dobTextField.text);
            [self.dobTextField resignFirstResponder];
            [self.dateOfDiagnosisTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        } else {
            self.dobTextField.text = nil;
            [self.dobTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps it's just taking the second choice (`else`). It clears the field.

Comment: What path does your code take? What has debugging revealed?

Comment: I'm getting a very similar error, with a UITextField not becoming first responder after showing an alertView, in iOS8.3 only. It was working fine before upgrade.

Comment: Same here. It's strange because even if you explicitly call becomeFirstResponder on the text field, the text field only becomes "half" first responder. The cursor shows up on the text field, but it doesn't blink and the keyboard does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem in my app by replacing my UIAlertViews with UIAlertControllers. This was very time consuming but since UIAlertView has been deprecated, it seemed prudent.

Comment: Interesting.  I partially solved my issue by removing the resign and become from the alert View